# How to remove a wpf element on a canvas by it's tag name?

Tags: wpf, canvas

How can you remove a wpf element by some kind of name? So sth like :

```
// Bar is some kind of usercontrol
Bar b = new Bar();
b.Tag = "someId";
theCanvas.Children.Add(b);

// Later to be removed without having the reference 
theCanvas.Children.RemoveElementWithTag("someId")
```

Except ofcourse, RemoveElementWithTag isn't an existing method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just use some LINQ:

```
var child = (from c in theCanvas.Children
             where "someId".Equals(c.Tag)
             select c).First();
theCanvas.Children.Remove(child);
```

That said, I highly suspect there's a cleaner, better performing way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: +1, since you could.  I did it like that first, now I am using a dictionary for that.  But is there really no way to get an element by id or sth?

Comment: Since the Children collection does only support getting things by id or reference there is no other way than to use LINQ/foreach to find the right element.